# UISeachController bar with SearchButtons grows in the wrong direction

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

Here is a search bar

[image: Normal Search bar..]

When I add the buttons by clikcing in the search bar it grows up and doesn't shift the table down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set button height constraint, take IBOutlayout of button height
 constraint. Set Button height constraint to particular height when to show it otherwise 0.

Second thing, give table top to Button so it will take proper space in button hide/show case

Comment: The UITableView is contrained to the top of the VC with a value of 55

Comment: Remove it and give it to Buttons

Comment: Give it to buttons?

Comment: Give UITAbleview top constrained to the buttons

Comment: What buttons? They buttons are not buttons but dynamically generated by the search bar. They are PART of the searchbar and the table is INSIDE of the table in the header.

Comment: Then set tableview top constraint dynmaic by setting top constraint, taking top constraint IBOutlet..